# Tag deletion request: unknown

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

It's [unknown](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unknown) to me what this tag is supposed to mean.

- Unrecognized hardware ("unknown device")?
- Default file editor, or file type associations ("unknown file types")?
- What is this file? ("unknown file")?
- [WTF is this plastic part that came with my laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/414029/mystery-plastic-part)

If you knew it, you wouldn't be asking questions here. Seems pretty meta to me.

[image: Trogdor, we need you!]

Comment: Surprisingly, we only have [one question](http://superuser.com/questions/334632/windows-xp-repair-messed-up-my-boot) regarding the `unknown software exception` exception!

Comment: @iglvzx And it's not tagged `unknown`, `software`, *or* `exception`. Clearly someone's doing something wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with removing these. There's only 12 questions with this tag, would anyone object to me just removing them from these questions? (Will also clean the questions too, of course)